# Change model attribute in ActiveRecord in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Person'
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :grandchildren, class_name: 'Person', through: :children, source: :children
end
```

I want this model to work that way (doesn't matter how):

```
grandfather = Person.create(name: "Grandfather")
father = Person.create(name: "Father", parent: grandfather)
son = Person.create(name: "Son", parent: father)

grandfather.children.map(&:name)
=> ['father']
grandfather.grandchildren.map(&:name)
=> ['Son']
```

So the idea is to get children's name downcased. I can use callbacks or override getter of name attribute, but this apply to both children and grandchildren, so that's not the point.

Comment: First of all, why not just explicitly downcase the names where you need it? Seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @OleksiiFilonenko I'm learning Rails and it's part of the exercise, so it doesn't need to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I can guess that task is in adding a knowledge about record being a "son", but not a "grandson". So you have a directional tree, and need to know each node's depth:

```rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  def depth
    (parent&.depth || 0) + 1
  end

  def name
    if depth == 2
      super.downcase
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Note that this is not efficient for large data structures with deep nesting, there it's better to materialise this into additional attribute that should be calculated upon setting parent.